# Getting Stellar.js to work with iscroll.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, iscroll

I'm trying to create a parralax scrolling website that works on the desktop and mobile. There is a great example of how to use Steller.js here:

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/create-a-parallax-scrolling-website-using-stellar-js/

The problem is this example doesn't work on iOS mobile. In order to get [Stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/) to work with iOS you can use [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll).

The creator of Steller.js gives a great turorial on how to incorporate Steller.js with iScroll.js here: http://markdalgleish.com/2012/10/mobile-parallax-with-stellar-js/

The first step is to create a couple of divs for iScroll, namely a “wrapper” div and a “scroller” div:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="scroller">

    <section>...</section>

  </div>
</div>
```

But when I put a wrapper around the content of the example the whole layout gets broken, like this:

[image]

Please could someone help me incorporate iScroll correctly to this example. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you add the CSS from the example required to make it work? `#wrapper {position:absolute}` and all that?